# maintain constant space between bars irrespective of number of bars google bar chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am using google bar chart and using following code.

```
var options = {       
    backgroundColor:'',
    title: '',        
    chartArea: {width: '100%'},
    bar: { groupWidth:15},
    colors: ['#fff', '#fff'],
    hAxis: {
      title: '',
      minValue: 0,
      gridlines: {
          color: '#fff'
      },
      baselineColor:'#fff',

      textStyle:{
        color:"#000"
      }

    },
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    vAxis: {
      title: '',      
      textPosition:'none' 

    }
};
```

I am getting following output

First case:when number of bars are more.

[image]

Second case: when number of bars are less.

[image]

Third case: when there is only one bar, it is showing in center. I want to start bar from bottom means near x-axis. Following you can see screen shot.

[image]

I want to show constant space between 2 bars irrespective of number of bars.

any advice or suggestion in this case?

Comment: maybe try using a percentage instead of a set number for `groupWidth` -- `groupWidth: '15%'`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it did not work